# Redirected to store base URL instead of custom admin URL

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, sales-order, base-url

In case of Custom Admin URL (in System -> [Advanced] Admin -> Admin Base URL) is set to something like http://mytreasure.store.com after creation of order or invoicing it Magento redirects back to the base url. I pin-pointed this to the store view change to the one order being assigned to

But whatever this is a bug or misconfiguration I really wonder

Magento is CE 1.7 fully patched

Comment: This is a slightly related topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095047/creating-an-admin-url-for-magento-that-is-admin-magentostore-com-not-admin

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate this with a vanila CE 1.7.0.2 install.

Comment: @SteveRobbins Interesting. Two separate nodes?

Answer (score 2):

There is a different method some prefer with changing the admin url. See [here](http://addoa.com/blog/ten-tips-keeping-your-magento-store-secure), [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20141210024646-1143212-22-ways-to-bulletproof-your-magento-security), and [here](http://www.simplehelix.com/blog/magento/securing-magento-beyond-the-password/) where they mention such a bug. Here is the approach they all recommend:

- open app/etc/local.xml
- find the line `<frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>` (it should be near the end of the file)
- change `[admin]` to `[customurl]`
- erase everything in the `var/cache` folder

Comment: Thanks for the response but it's not about the way to secure the instance. The custom URL is being used but also subdomain is which leads to this broken redirect